# One-liner to remove duplicates, keep ordering of list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
['Herb', 'Alec', 'Herb', 'Don']
```

I want to remove duplicates while keeping the order, so it would be :

```
['Herb', 'Alec', 'Don']
```

Here is how I would do this verbosely:

```
l_new = []
for item in l_old:
    if item not in l_new: l_new.append(item)
```

Is there a way to do this in a single line?

Comment: @Dekel I understand, my question is looking for a one-liner though to do that.

Comment: many of the answers from that question have one liners using different approaches

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an `OrderedDict`, but I suggest sticking with your for-loop.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = ['Herb', 'Alec', 'Herb', 'Don']
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data))
['Herb', 'Alec', 'Don']
```

Just to reiterate: I **seriously suggest** sticking with your for-loop approach, and use a `set` to keep track of already seen items:

```
>>> data = ['Herb', 'Alec', 'Herb', 'Don']
>>> seen = set()
>>> unique_data = []
>>> for x in data:
...     if x not in seen:
...         unique_data.append(x)
...         seen.add(x)
...
>>> unique_data
['Herb', 'Alec', 'Don']
```

And in case you just want to be wacky (**seriously don't do this**):

```
>>> [t[0] for t in sorted(dict(zip(reversed(data), range(len(data), -1, -1))).items(), key=lambda t:t[1])]
['Herb', 'Alec', 'Don']
```

Comment: Why would you suggest against the above though?

Comment: @David542 because it is inefficient and not explicit. Indeed, almost any one-liner will be, I suspect.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I've edited to explicitly include what I *meant* to imply.

Comment: [`OrderedDict.fromkeys` is a class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys), no? So there's no need to create an `OrderedDict` instance. `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data))` would work.

Comment: @ChristianDean yep, silly mistake on my  part. Thanks for pointing it out. I think I originally started writing something like `OrderedDict((k, None) for k in data)` and then was like, oh wait, `.fromkeys`already exists...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No worries. I think we've all made that mistake trying to post our answer as fast as possible. Classic FGITW side-effects. Oh, and by the way, that last method burned my eyes ;-)

Answer (score 15):

You could use a set to remove duplicates and then restore ordering. And it's just as slow as your original, yaeh :-)

```
>>> sorted(set(l_old), key=l_old.index)
['Herb', 'Alec', 'Don']
```

Comment: Hah! I find that solutions hilarious! It's inspired me as well...

Answer (score 8):

Using pandas, create a series from the list, drop duplicates, and then convert it back to a list.

```
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.Series(['Herb', 'Alec', 'Herb', 'Don']).drop_duplicates().tolist()
['Herb', 'Alec', 'Don']
```

**Timings**

[Solution from @StefanPochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45746446/7009806) is the clear winner for lists with high duplication.

```
my_list = ['Herb', 'Alec', 'Don'] * 10000

%timeit pd.Series(my_list).drop_duplicates().tolist()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.11 ms per loop

%timeit list(OrderedDict().fromkeys(my_list))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop

%timeit sorted(set(my_list), key=my_list.index)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 396 µs per loop
```

For larger lists with no duplication (e.g. simply a range of numbers), the pandas solution is very fast.

```
my_list = range(10000)

%timeit pd.Series(my_list).drop_duplicates().tolist()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop

%timeit list(OrderedDict().fromkeys(my_list))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop

%timeit sorted(set(my_list), key=my_list.index)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 716 ms per loop
```

Comment: How fitting for you to use _pandas_ ;-)

Comment: @ChristianDean A pandas developer using pandas... shocking.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You realize I'm talking about his profile picture, right?

Comment: @ChristianDean I do, but I think you got it backwards. I think it's the pic that's fitting his use of pandas, not the other way around.

Comment: @Alexander While I do like winning things, I do need to point out that your test case is extreeeemely unfair towards the other solutions (because it's unreasonably good for mine).

Comment: I know..... (-;  Just didn't want to write too many cases (small lists, larget lists with little duplicates, large list with lots of duplicates...). Your solution is still very good.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't care about optimizations and stuff you can use the following:

```
s = ['Herb', 'Alec', 'Herb', 'Don']
[x[0] for x in zip(s, range(len(s))) if x[0] not in s[:x[1]]]
```

> Note that in my opinion you really should use the `for` loop in your question or the answer by @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1):

```
l_new = []
for item in l_old:
    if item not in l_new: l_new.append(item)
```

In one line..ish:

```
l_new = []

[ l_new.append(item)  for item in l_old if item not in l_new]
```

Which has the behavior:

```
> a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5]
> b = []
> [ b.append(item) for item in a if item not in b]
> print(b)
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Your one-line solution needs a semicolon: `l_new = []; [l_new.append(item)  for item in l_old if item not in l_new]`

Comment: But that would be cheating :P

Comment: Then do it *inside* the comprehension.

Comment: @StefanPochmann uhhhh.... how? Sorry if naive question, I don't know how to declare something inside a list comprehension

Comment: @Erich Huh? You're already doing that. With `item`. Ok, here's a way: `[l_new.append(item) or l_new for l_new in [[]] for item in l_old if item not in l_new][0]`

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I thought that I would have to create something which existed outside of the scope of the comprehension but your empty list trick is very cool :)

Comment: Or in Python 2 you could do `[0 for tmp in [[]]] and [tmp.append(item) for item in l_old if item not in tmp] and tmp`. But don't tell anyone that I said that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
l = ['Herb', 'Alec', 'Herb', 'Don']
data = [i[-1] for i in sorted([({a:i for i, a in enumerate(l)}[a], a) for a in set({a:i for i, a in enumerate(l)}.keys())], key = lambda x: x[0])]
```

Output:

```
['Alec', 'Herb', 'Don']
```

This algorithm merely removes the first instance of a duplicate value.